# Configuring Nginx to redirect different servers

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup Nginx to redirect different domains to a single one - `http://knyt.tl`:

```
server {
  listen 81;
  server_name _;
  return 302 http://knyt.tl/;
  rewrite ^ http://knyt.tl permanent;
}

server {
    listen 81;
    server_name knyt.tl;        
}
```

However nginx just returns contents of the domain `knyt.tl` and the different domains are not redirected with neither `return 302`, nor `rewrite ^`.

I've also tried following:

```
server {
    listen 81;

    if ($host != 'knyt.tl') {
        rewrite ^ http://knyt.tl/ permanent;
    }
 }
```

But the clause seems to be completely ignored as well.

Only time I managed to get it running was when redirecting from `www.knyt.tl` to `knyt.tl`.

Comment: You're listening on port 81. Are you using something else to actually answer requests on port 80? That's where you need to look for the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am running apache on 80 and I don't want them to interfere.

Comment: Then you also need to look at (and post here) your Apache configuration.

Comment: But I don't see a reason why they should interact - I suppose if I tell `nginx` to use port 81, why should he care about port 80?

Comment: Because all of your requests come in on port 80, so Apache is touching them all.

Comment: Disabling apache seems to solve the problem. If you post recommendation as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nginx listening on port 81. But you have Apache actually answering requests on port 80. That's where you need to look for the problem, since all of your incoming requests come in on port 80.